# Length contraction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames

I was looking at the proof of length contraction and I am a bit confused. If we have two frames S and S', where S' is moving at v relative to S, The length of the rod in S' is $ x^{1}_{AB} = l_0 $, which is the proper length.

To find the length of the rod in S, we use the SR transformation,

$ x^1_{AB} = \gamma ( x_{AB} - v t_{AB}) $

Setting $t_{AB} = 0$, gets the desired result. I'm a bit confused by this. $t_{AB}$ is the time to measure the rod in S, lab frame. I would've thought that the time to measure the rod in the rods rest frame $t^1_{AB} = 0 $. Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: The end of the rod is at $x^1_{AB}=l_0$ for all $t^1_{AB}$ because by assumption it is *at rest* in this frame. You want to know where the end of this rod is located with respect to an observer in the other frame relative to which the rod's frame is moving. So it only makes sense that the answer depends on this other's frame time measurement, as with respect to this frame the end of the rod is changing its position with respect to time.

Comment: MultiDuplicate :  ...[2.175 posts on  length-contraction](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=length+contraction)...

Comment: @Frobenius  I wonder how the odd 7/40 of a post came about... [Sorry]

Comment: This question is neither homework-like nor check-my-work. It is clearly conceptual. It didn't show up on a scan of previous questions on length contraction.

Comment: The best advice anyone can give is Draw a Spacetime Diagram, and it will become clear.

Answer (score 3):

"The length of the rod in S' is $[\Delta] ^1_{}=l_0$, which is the proper length." This implies that the rod is at rest in the S' frame. In that case, in order to measure the rod's length, it doesn't matter whether you note the positions ($x_A^1$ and $x_B^1$, say) of the ends of the rod at the same time or at different times; in either case $\Delta ^1_{}=x_B^1-x_A^1$.

But in the S frame, in which the rod is moving, you clearly need to note the positions ($x_A$ and $x_B$, say) of the ends of the rod at the same time ($t_A = t_B$ so $\Delta t_{AB}=0$). [You wouldn't get a correct length by subtraction ($\Delta _{}=x_B-x_A$) if you noted the position of one end, waited a while and then noted the position of the other end!]

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding this is understanding the proposed form of the measurement of the length. To obtain length contraction, one has the following measuring process: Assume you have 2 inertial systems K and K', one of which moves with velocity $\vec v = v \vec e_x$ relative to the other and at t = t' = 0, they are identical. Now assume in K' there is a rod, at rest. Now at every point of the x-axis of K there is someone at precisely at $t=t_0$ they all look whether at their point the rod ends or starts. That way the starting point and the end point of the rod is found out. 
Therefore $t_{AB} = 0$ by definition of the measuring process.

The definition of the measuring process is very important and essential to understanding why several apparent kinematical paradoxes actually aren't paradox. It is also the reason that the world looks a lot weirder than just contracted lengths when you are moving very quickly.